# Informix Query Tuning

Tags: informix

I have a table called lead, which have about 500 thousand records and we need the following query to get executed.

```
SELECT skip 300000 first 75 *  
  FROM lead 
 WHERE ((enrollment_period IS NULL) OR 
(enrollment_period IN ('FT2015','F16','SUM2016','FALL2016','FALL2017','SP17'))) 
 ORDER BY created_on DESC
```

The table lead has id column as the primary key and thus have clustered index in that column.  This query is taking about 12 - 13 mins.  When I added a non-clustered index on created_on and enrollment_period columns, it came down to 4 - 5 mins.  Then I changed the clustered index from id column to this index, execution time came down further to about 50 seconds now.

Is there any other optimization scope available for this query?
Overall, is there any other change that can be done so that the query will execute faster?

Thanks in Advance,
Manohar

Comment: You'd probably do better replacing the SKIP clause with a condition in the WHERE clause based on date/time, assuming `created_on` is in fact an indexed column with a date/time type.  The SKIP clause requires stuff to be sorted.  What are you really trying to do?  Why rows 300001..300075 in order of creation?

Comment: The purpose of skip is pagination.  I am giving the query above because in User Interface, the user may even scroll to skip 300000 records.  Kindly let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Don't do the pagination by numbers; do it by range of `created_on`?  How many of your users actually scroll through 300,000 records?  Even if you read 3 per second, that's more than a full day's worth of scrolling.  If you 'read' (scan) 75 per second, you're still talking about working for an hour to get to row 300,000.  Are you in the backend behind a web server or other stateless interface?  In the good old days (say late 1980's), you could use a scroll cursor, but the stateless operations make that harder.

Comment: Unfortunatrely, client requirement is such that they could swiftly scroll the cursor in the web interface.  It is basically a JPA data layer and the application is hosted in Glassfish server.